# Carplay Application not showing on iOS 13 simulator

Tags: swift, ios13, carplay, xcode11

I have developed application for Automotive CarPlay. App working properly for iOS 11 and 12 Carplay Simulator. I am trying to run application on iOS 13 CarPlay simulator but app not appearing on CarPlay simulator.

I have run below commands :

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlayExtraOptions -bool YES
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlayProtocols -array-add com.mycarbundle.app
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlay -bool YES
```

[image]

**1.Carplay Connect**

```swift
NotificationCenter.default
    .addObserver(forName: UIScreen.didConnectNotification,
                  object: nil,
                   queue: .main) { (notification) in
     print("Carplay Connected")
}
```

**2.Carplay DisConnect**

```swift
NotificationCenter.default
    .addObserver(forName: UIScreen.didDisconnectNotification,
                  object: nil,
                   queue: .main) { (notification) in
    print("Carplay DisConnected")
}
```

This method not getting called.
Please help me if anyone has done in iOS 13?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 11.0 and 11.2.1 versions not showing carplay apps in simulator. It was a xcode bug. It's working now on Xcode 11.3 beta.